# Ubuntu server console and SSH session freezes

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-14.04

I have Ubuntu server 14.04 installed on a virtual box VM and for some reason it has begun to freeze during login and after some commands. When I try to login from console it can hang for minutes after entering password and when I finally get in, that session can run smoothly for a short while but after some commands it freezes again. Same problem with other tty sessions.

When I try to login with ssh it usually times out before I can enter password and sometimes after I have entered my password it times out.

I've verified that CPU and memory utilization is low so I'm puzzled about what could be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my problem was because of ldap being blocked by ufw. So every time I tried to authenticate with a username not present in /etc/passwd it would try to access a remote ldap database but since it was blocked it waited until timeout and hence did not prompt for password.

When I tried to authenticate with a local user, I was prompted for password but then it hanged after that probably because it was trying to contact LDAP database but was blocked.